# Tag image in Google Container Registry with Docker API for Python

Tags: python, docker, google-container-registry

I have a project in Google Cloud and I want to tag image in Container Registry with new_tag. I wrote code:

```
import docker

cli = docker.from_env()
img = cli.images.get('my_image:latest')
tagged = img.tag('my_image:new_tag')
print('image tagged: ' + str(tagged))
```

How could I set arguments for docker.from_env such as host (gcr.io), project (my_project) and authentication with google cloud service account?

Comment: Have you tried with the python script you have provided? Also do you only want to add a new tag to the image in Google Container Registry? For that you can use `gcloud` commands as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#tagging_images).

Comment: @Prabir This script works good locally but I need to connect to remote repository (gcr.io). Yes, I only want to tag an existing image. And I know how to do it with gcloud command but I want to make simple application with frontend to be able to tag the required image with new tag in browser

Answer (score 0):

As Google Container Registry is a remote registry, it is not possible to directly add a tag there from the local system other than using gcloud as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#tagging_images).

There is a way to add a new tag by running a python script. For that you have to -

1. Pull the image from Google Container Registry
2. Add a new tag to it locally
3. Push the newly tagged image to Google Container Registry

The following python script works well for this task :

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
base_url = "gcr.io/project-id/demo-image"
#existing tag of the image in gcr
from_url=":tag1"
#desired tag to be added
to_tag = ":tag2"
#pull the image from container registry to local system
client.images.pull(base_url+from_url)
#get the image from local system and add a new tag to it
client.images.get(base_url+from_url).tag(base_url+to_tag)
#push the newly tagged image to container registry
client.images.push(base_url+to_tag)
#remove the pulled image from local system
client.images.remove(base_url+to_tag)
#remove the newly tagged image from local system
client.images.remove(base_url+from_url)
```

Answer (score -1):

Write a python program that aks user to input 10 integrrs . It then performs the following :
-prints maximum , minimum number in the list
-prints largest odd number in the list .if no odd number in the input ,print "No odd
Number"
For example :
Input     result
10        120
20         5
30         101
40
5
6
7
90
101
120

2        100
4         2
6       no odd number
8
10
20
30
40
50
80
100

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to be an interview question? Not sure how this is related to the original post.